# EF-Reference.Load() - There is already an open DataReader

Tags: entity-framework, sql-server-mars

Looks like EF Reference.Load() is not working without MARS? Is that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right. Not much more to say than that!

Comment: Than EF mysql, is not supporting Load and than the only way to Load reference is through Select.

Comment: dynback, MARS is a SQL Server issue only. The EF Provider for SQL Server requires MARS. MySQL has its own provider which may or may not require specific MySQL features to be used. But MySQL requirements have nothing to do with MARS, and the requirements imposed by the SQL Server EF provider have nothing to do with MySQL; they're completely separate issues.

Comment: Craig, i am not sure about MARS itself, I know only that Reference.Load is not working in mysql EF implementation, because of "There is already an open DataReader"

Comment: OK, then you need to ask a different question. :)